# Small multiples line plot

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a small multiples line plot from a data frame which looks something like this:

```
Time    A   B   C   D
2013-01-01  69.23580    8.708641    NaN 3.452663
2013-02-01  69.46016    8.353662    NaN 4.601604
2013-03-01  69.62315    9.156498    NaN 3.953704
2013-04-01  71.04144    7.817074    NaN 3.762032
2013-05-01  74.29557    7.971487    NaN 4.475369
```

I would ideally want 4 plots on a single graph showing line plots for each of the variables in my data frame. I am using the following code (after `melt`ing the data frame) but it gives me some very weird results.

```
q <- ggplot(data=temp) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=value, color=variable), size = 1) + 
  facet_grid(variable~value) +
  xlab("Time")
```

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you would think about using the [facet_wrap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) function.

And the `scales` argument will change the scale since fixed is the default option.

> should scales be fixed ("fixed", the default), free ("free"), or free in one dimension ("free_x", "free_y")

```
data_text <- "
Time    A   B   C   D
2013-01-01  69.23580    8.708641    NaN 3.452663
2013-02-01  69.46016    8.353662    NaN 4.601604
2013-03-01  69.62315    9.156498    NaN 3.953704
2013-04-01  71.04144    7.817074    NaN 3.762032
2013-05-01  74.29557    7.971487    NaN 4.475369
"
temp <- read.table(text=data_text, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(reshape2)

temp <- melt(temp, id.vars=c("Time"))
temp$Time <- as.Date(temp$Time)
library(ggplot2)

library(plyr)
temp <- subset(temp, value > 0)
q2 <- ggplot(data=temp) + geom_line(aes(x=Time, y=value, color=variable), size = 1) + facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y")

q2
```

[image]

Comment: @Patthebug Can we delete our discussions in the comment since they actually don't provide any value for future readers. Good to know that is helpful.